# Python Plot on Image with Animation

Tags: python, animation, setinterval

I want to draw out points in succession for each new position `i` while clearing previous frames to visualize the movement. Am I on the right track? I'm used to coding this in Javascript using the `setinterval` function but I'm new to Python.

```
fig = plt.figure(1)
    ax  = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.imshow(img, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
    ax.set_xticks([])
    ax.set_yticks([])
    ax.set_xlim(0,img.shape[1])
    ax.plot(np.r_[x,x[0]], np.r_[y,y[0]], c=(0.5,0.5,0.5), lw=1)

    for i, snake in enumerate(snakePoints):
        if i % 15 == 0:
            ax.plot(np.r_[snake[0], snake[0][0]], np.r_[snake[1], snake[1][0]], c=(0.1,0,1,0.3), lw=1)


    ax.plot(np.r_[snakePoints[-1][0], snakePoints[-1][0][0]], np.r_[snakePoints[-1][1], snakePoints[-1][1][0]], c=(1,0,0), lw=3)
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

try using  below

```
ax.clear() # to clear the previous output

plt.pause(0.001) # to pause and show animation for new plot
```

and write a function to call with new parameters and plot. Your indentation is wrong I suppose.